# Adding entries to a map in a loop

Tags: for-loop, dictionary, go

I am trying to implement in my application a way to separate users per country and then, send them to different actions.

This is what I have right now:

```
var manyUsers zendesk.ManyUsers
users := make(map[string]zendesk.ManyUsers)

for {
    ...
    manyUsers.AppendUsers(mysqlRequest(country, id))
    users[country] = manyUsers

    fmt.Printf("[%s]: %#v\n\n", country, users[country])
}
```

But I figure out that after when I add a 3 different countries, it will generate 3 diferent keys, but the last one will have the 3 users from the other countries.

This is my AppendUsers function

```
func (users *ManyUsers) AppendUsers(user User) []User {
    users.Users = append(users.Users, user)

    return users.Users
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to thanks @kostix and @cloudaice for the answers.

I figure out what I need to do, I used what @kostix suggested, so I create in each iteration in my `for` loop, the `var manyUsers zendesk.ManyUsers` but I also added the follow:

```
manyUsers = users[country]
manyUsers.AppendUsers(mysqlRequest(country, id))
users[country] = manyUsers
```

Passing the current value from each country to my `manyUsers` I am capable of add a new `User` element in the `ManyUsers` struct and return the appended value to the `users[country]`. So, I never aggregate data from iteration and each country gets the correct amount of users.

Thank you.

Comment: Consider accepting your own answer then -- that's what SO rules suggest to do anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You essentially modifying *the same* variable `manyUsers` on each iteration of your `for` loop and use that single instance as the value each time you create the new map entry.

You did not show us how your `zendesk.ManyUser` is defined but if it has reference semantics all your map entries will share the same data.

My guess (given the incomplete problem statement) is that you need to create a new instance of `zendesk.ManyUser` on each iteraition of your loop:

```
users := make(map[string]zendesk.ManyUsers)

for {
    ...
    var manyUsers zendesk.ManyUsers
    manyUsers.AppendUsers(mysqlRequest(country, id))
    users[country] = manyUsers

    fmt.Printf("[%s]: %#v\n\n", country, users[country])
}
```

A no-brainer demonstration of the effect [is there](https://play.golang.org/p/6m6lAK0EeI) — observe that the iterations of the first loop modify the same variable while in the second loop each iteration first gets a fresh instance of a variable.

Answer (score 0):

the type of  manyUsers is value not reference，so the follow code maybe ok

```
var manyUsers *zendesk.ManyUsers
users := make(map[string]*zendesk.ManyUsers)
......
```